# Laravel Creating default object from empty value when canceled booking rooms

Tags: laravel

ia geeting eror when i am canceled booking rooms , the eror message

**"Creating default object from empty value"**

this is my **booking controller**

```
public function cancel($room_id, $booking_id) {
    $booking = Booking::find($booking_id);
    $room = Room::find($room_id);
    $booking->status = 0;
    $room->status = 1;
    $booking->save();
    $room->save();
    session()->flash('msg','Booking has been canceled');
    return redirect('/booking');
}

public function canceledBookings() {
    $canceledBookings = Booking::where('status', 0)->get();
    return view('bookings.canceled', compact('canceledBookings'));
}
```

when i canceled booking on user.. the page return error 
**"Creating default object from empty value"**

please HELP ME...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a record with given ID in DB and one of these returns `null`:

```
$booking = Booking::find($booking_id);
$room = Room::find($room_id);
```

You can check for `null`:

```
if (is_null($booking))
```

Or you can use the `firstOrNew()`:

```
$booking = Booking::findOrNew($booking_id);
$room = Room::findOrNew($room_id);
```

In case if there is no record, a new one will be created.

Comment: hey Alexey .. i can to use findOrNew.. but i have the error ..


"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`backend`.`bookings`, CONSTRAINT `bookings_room_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `rooms` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `bookings` (`status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, 2018-02-20 13:39:46, 2018-02-20 13:39:46)

Comment: @bimoan it's not related. This means you need to set `room_id` before saving `Booking` object.

Comment: how to set room_id ? before saving Booking object..  there are references I can learn.. ??
i am newbie on laravel ..

Comment: @bimoan save the room first, then do `$booking->room_id = $room->id;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Find change see below code
First check you data Booking Information & Room Information

```
 public function cancel($room_id, $booking_id) {
    $booking = Booking::where('id',$booking_id)->first();
    $booking->status = 0;
    $booking->save();

    $room = Room::where('id',$room_id)->first();    
    $room->status = 1;    
    $room->save();
    session()->flash('msg','Booking has been canceled');
    return redirect('/booking');
}
```

Comment: hy Sagar.. when i try to

Booking::where('id',$booking_id)->first();
Room::where('id',$room_id)->first();    

the problem is same.. still eror